# How to regroup what's under a threshold with linq?

Tags: vb.net, linq

Say I have a list of string with specific names :

```
APP_application1.exe
APP_application2.exe
APP_application3.exe
APP_application4.exe
CMD_Batch.exe
PWS_Script.exe
PWS_Script2.exe
PWS_Script3.exe
VBS_Script.exe
VBS_Script2.exe
[...]
```

I want to regroup those with the same prefix together but only if they are over a threshold. Those under that limit are bundled together in an "other" tag. I also want a maximum of 5 groups.

```
Group APP : {APP_application1.exe,APP_application2.exe,APP_application3.exe,APP_application4.exe}
Group PWS : {PWS_Script.exe,PWS_Script2.exe,PWS_Script3.exe}
Group other : {CMD_Batch.exe,VBS_Script.exe,VBS_Script2.exe}
```

Right now, I have hardcoded my groups, so I can filter with a prefix

```
filtered = _
    (From cell In listFiles _
        Where cell.ToUpper().StartsWith(prefix)
        Select New SelectListItem() With { _
            .Text = cell, _
            .Value = cell _
        }).ToList()
```

Or filter with those outside it :

```
filtered = _
    (From cell In listFiles _
        Let prefix = cell.Substring(0, 3).ToUpper()
        Where Not LIST_CODE.Contains(prefix)
        Select New SelectListItem() With { _
            .Text = cell, _
            .Value = cell _
        }).ToList()
```

Where `LISTE_CODE = {"APP","PWS"}`
I want to get rid of `LISTE_CODE` and use something like `MIN_GROUP_SIZE = 3` and `MAX_GROUP = 5`, to be more dynamic.

Right now I have

```
Dim grp =
    (From cell In listFiles _
     Let prefixe = cell.Substring(0.3).ToUpper()
     Group By pre = prefixe Into g = Group
     Where g.Count() < MIN_GROUP_SIZE
     Select g)
```

But it doesn't group at all.

Do I have the right approach?
What's wrong with my `group by`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd proceed in smaller steps.
(Error handling is not included.)

```
var names = new string[] {
    "APP_application1.exe",
    "APP_application2.exe",
    "APP_application3.exe",
    "APP_application4.exe",
    "CMD_Batch.exe",
    "PWS_Script.exe",
    "PWS_Script2.exe",
    "PWS_Script3.exe",
    "VBS_Script.exe",
    "VBS_Script2.exe"
};

var MIN_GROUP_SIZE = 2;
var MAX_GROUP = 2;

// Helper to extract the uppercase prefix
Func<string, string> GetPrefix = (name) => name.Split('_')[0].ToUpper();

var groupsForPrefixes = names.GroupBy(name => GetPrefix(name));
// Collect the prefixes for the first MAX_GROUP groups that have at least MIN_GROUP_SIZE items
var prefixes = groupsForPrefixes.Where(grp => grp.Count() >= MIN_GROUP_SIZE).Take(MAX_GROUP).Select(grp => grp.Key);

var groupsOfNames = names.GroupBy(name => prefixes.Contains(GetPrefix(name)) ? GetPrefix(name) : "OTHER");
```

The result in LINQPad

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<String,String>> (3 items) 

Key= APP 

IGrouping<String,String> (4 items) 
    App_application1.exe 
    APP_application2.exe 
    APP_application3.exe 
    APP_application4.exe 

Key= OTHER 

IGrouping<String,String> (3 items) 
    CMD_Batch.exe 
    VBS_Script.exe 
    VBS_Script2.exe 

Key= PWS 

IGrouping<String,String> (3 items) 
    PWS_Script.exe 
    PWS_Script2.exe 
    PWS_Script3.exe
```

Forgive me my using C# instead of VB; I hope it helps anyway.

Here it is now in VB (converted with the Telerik Code Converter Service).

```
    Dim names = New String() {
    "APP_application1.exe",
    "APP_application2.exe",
    "APP_application3.exe",
    "APP_application4.exe",
    "CMD_Batch.exe",
    "PWS_Script.exe",
    "PWS_Script2.exe",
    "PWS_Script3.exe",
    "VBS_Script.exe",
    "VBS_Script2.exe"}

    Dim MIN_GROUP_SIZE = 2
    Dim MAX_GROUP = 2

    ' Helper to extract the uppercase prefix
    Dim GetPrefix As Func(Of String, String) = Function(name) name.Split("_"c)(0).ToUpper()

    Dim groupsForPrefixes = names.GroupBy(Function(name) GetPrefix(name))
    ' Collect the prefixes for the first MAX_GROUP groups that have at least MIN_GROUP_SIZE items
    Dim prefixes = groupsForPrefixes.Where(Function(grp) grp.Count() >= MIN_GROUP_SIZE).Take(MAX_GROUP).[Select](Function(grp) grp.Key)

    Dim groupsOfNames = names.GroupBy(Function(name) If(prefixes.Contains(GetPrefix(name)), GetPrefix(name), "OTHER"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could achieve your goal.

Using lookups is a great way to partition your result sets.  You can use this to your advantage to determine what is within the threshold and recombine those that are not.

```
Dim threshold = 3
Dim grouped =
    From name In names
    Let prefix = name.Split("_"c).First.ToUpper
    Group name By prefix Into Group, Count
Dim partition = grouped.ToLookup(
    Function(x) x.Count >= threshold,
    Function(x) New With { x.Group, x.prefix }
)
Dim query = partition(True).Concat(
    From x In partition(False)
    From name In x.Group
    Group name By prefix = "OTHER" Into Group
    Select New With { Group, prefix }).ToList
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it in 2 parts :

```
        Dim listGroup = From listeCmd In listFiles
                     Let prefixe = listeCmd.Substring(0, 3).ToUpper()
                     Group By prefix Into Group
                     Order By Group.Count() Descending

        listeB = listeGroup.Where(Function(e) e.Group.Count >= MIN_ITEM_PR_PREFIX) _
                                 .Take(MAX_GROUPE) _
                                 .Select(Function(e) e.prefix).ToList()
```

This gave me my list of group's name, which I used to replace my `LIST_CODE` const.

This is quite similar to Attila Karoly's answer.